# how to fix the error (Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable) in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unty2D and I have this error
here's the code

```
 float startSize;

   void Start()
   {
       startSize = this.GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize;

   }


    void Update() {
        var targetScrips =  target.GetComponent<controller>;

        if(targetScrips.isMove)
        this.GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp (this.GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize, startSize, Time.time * 0.001f);
        else
        this.GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp (this.GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize, startSize, Time.time * 0.003f);
```

how to fix?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkjl.png)

Comment: It helps getting answers if you tag the correct programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing some parenthesis

> var targetScrips =  target.GetComponent < controller >();